# Full width layout with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to accomplish a layout similar to this one: 
http://dribbble.com/shots/829195-Slate/attachments/86422

My project uses Twitter Bootstrap with responsive design. It is possible to implement a full width layout with Bootstrap?

The issue is that from what I've been reading fluid layouts will be removed in bootstrap 3.0, and the responsive design has fixed widths.

Comment: If you want a full width layout, just set your outer container to 100%, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: span's have fixed widths eg 570px. even if I add 100% they won't cover the whole page. <div class='row'><div class='span12'></div></div> won't cover the whole thing

Comment: It'd only have a fixed width if it's told to have one (e.g. in the CSS). Change 570px, to a percentage. If you'd like further help then it would be a good idea to post code and even a link to see where the problem lies.

Comment: I used the responsive design version of bootstrap.If you look at the source code https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less you'll see it uses fixed values. I'm worried about using fluid since I heard it's going to be removed in 3.0.

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/wiki/Upcoming-3.0-changes "Overhauled default grid system. Now uses percentage widths, padding, and box-sizing: border-box instead of pixel widths and margins."

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Because the accepted answer isn't on the same planet as BS3, I'll share what I'm using to achieve nearly full-width capabilities.

First off, this is cheating.  It's not really fluid width - but it appears to be - depending on the size of the screen viewing the site.

The problem with BS3 and fluid width sites is that they have taken this "mobile first" approach, which requires that they define every freaking screen width up to what they consider to be desktop (1200px)  I'm working on a laptop with a 1900px wide screen - so I end up with 350px on either side of the content at what BS3 thinks is a desktop sized width.

They have defined 10 screen widths (really only 5, but anyway).  I don't really feel comfortable changing those, because they are common widths. So, I chose to define some extra widths for BS to choose from when deciding the width of the container class.

The way I use BS is to take all of the Bootstrap provided LESS files, omit the variables.less file to provide my own, and add one of my own to the end to override the things I want to change.  Within my less file, I add the following to achieve 2 common screen width settings:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    .container {
        max-width: (1600px - @grid-gutter-width);
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1900px) {
    .container {
        max-width: (1900px - @grid-gutter-width);
    }
}
```

These two settings set the example for what you need to do to achieve different screen widths.  Here, you get full width at 1600px, and 1900px.  Any less than 1600 - BS falls back to the 1200px width, then to 768px and so forth - down to phone size.

If you have larger to support, just create more @media screen statements like these.  If you're building the CSS instead, you'll want to determine what gutter width was used and subtract it from your target screen width.

### Update:

**Bootstrap 3.0.1** and up (so far) - it's as easy as setting `@container-large-desktop` to `100%`

Comment: why omit variables.less?  can't you just add this to the end of it?  Just curious

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this and providing a simple workaround. I've found this frustrating in BS3.

Comment: @Phil: I don't omit variables.less, I use my own instead of the factory version.  And yes, I do add to the end of it.

Comment: Seems this fix doesn't work anymore with bootstrap 3.0.1 unfortunately

Comment: BS 3.0.1 and up (so far) - it's as easy as setting @container-large-desktop to 100%;

Comment: I believe that for BS 3.2 the best approach is now to simply change your container class to container-fluid as described in the answer by @zmt.

Answer (score 126):

You'll find a great tutorial here: [bootstrap-3-grid-introduction](http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction) and answer for your question is `<div class="container-fluid"> ... </div>`

Comment: I don't fully understand why the answer claims the class name to be `.container-liquid`, while the real Bootstrap class is in fact `.container-fluid`. Check yo sources: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: If anybody is using a Layout page (_Layout.cshtml), add container-fluid to the div that contains  @RenderBody()

Answer (score 11):

### Update:

Bootstrap 3 has been released since this question was originally answered in January, so if you are a BS3 user, please refer to the BS3 [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/). For those still on BS2, the original answer still applies. If you are interested in switching from 2 to 3, see the [migration](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration) guide.

### Original answer:

From the bootstrap 2 [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem):

> Make any row "fluid" by changing .row to .row-fluid. The column
>   classes stay the exact same, making it easy to flip between fixed and
>   fluid grids.

**Code**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4">...</div>
  <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>
```

This, in conjunction with setting the width of your container to a fluid value, should allow you to get your desired layout.

Comment: It will be removed in 3.0 but OK.

Comment: As Omega noted in the comments, the grid system is going to use percentage units in the future. Unless you can wait until Bootstrap 3 drops to start development, use the fluid measurements in 2. There are so many other changes coming in 3 that trying to make 2 "forwards compatible' is going to be more difficulty than it is worth IMHO. But I feel your pain : )

Answer (score 7):

As of the latest Bootstrap (3.1.x), the way to achieve a fluid layout it to use `.container-fluid` class.

See [Bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for reference

Answer (score 5):

Just create another class and add along with the bootstrap `container` class. You can also use `container-fluid` though.

```
<div class="container full-width">
    <div class="row">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS part is pretty simple

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
*{
   margin:0
   padding:0
}
```

make sure your container's width:%100

Comment: span's have fixed widths 570px. even if I add 100% they won't cover the whole page.

Comment: if you post your code we can try sth to fix this problem otherwise we cannot give you a proper solution way.

Answer (score 4):

In Bootstrap 3, columns are specified using percentages. (In Bootstrap 2, this was only the case if a column/span was within a `.row-fluid` element, but that's no longer necessary and that class no longer exists.) If you use a `.container`, then @Michael is absolutely right that you'll be stuck with a fixed-width layout. However, you should be in good shape if you just avoid using a .container element.

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">...</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The margin for the body is already 0, so you should be able to get up right to the edge. (Columns still have a 15px padding on both sides, so you may have to account for that in your design, but this shouldn't stop you, and you can always customize this when you download Bootstrap.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a 100% width, 100% height layout with Bootstrap 3.

http://bootply.com/tofficer/77686

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way with BS3 is to reset the max-width and padding set by BS3 CSS simply like this. You get again a container-fluid :

```
.container{
  max-width:100%;
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you could just use class "col-md-12" it has required left and right paddings and 100% width. Looks like this is a good replacement for container-fluid from 2nd bootstrap.

Comment: Only col-md-12 overflows for full screen width on Bootstrap-3.3.