# Bootstrap Grid, do I need a container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been playing with bootstrap 3 and I noticed that if you use the Grid System without a container it becomes fluid, someone told me I shouldn't do that because the system was design to be within a container. What happens if I don't use the container class?, do I need it?, if so could I make the container class width 100% without messing up bootstrap's media-queries, or is there any other or better way to build a fluid layout with bootstrap 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full width layout with twitter bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263307/full-width-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update Bootstrap 4**

Outermost rows should also be wrapping in `container` or `container-fluid` in Bootstrap 4 to prevent horizontal scolling caused by negative margins on the `.row`.

**Bootstrap 3**

You should wrap `row` in `container` or you'll have a problem with the negative margins that BS 3 uses for the `row` element. Basically the `row` is designed to be within a container. [Read more on the Bootstrap grid](https://medium.com/wdstack/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works-471d7a089cfc)

Play with this example on Bootply: http://bootply.com/83751

Answer (score 5):

According to the latest documentation:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/gutters/#no-gutters

it is reasonable to drop the outer container (or at least its css class assignment):

> Need an edge-to-edge design? Drop the parent .container or
> .container-fluid.

This appears to have been in the documentation since the 4.0 release: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: This might leave some white space on the right side. Adding "no-gutters" class to the row without a container fixed it for me.

Comment: This is still in the 5.1 (latest) documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/gutters/#no-gutters
For example for printables having containers breaks the layout (lots of overflow towards the right).

Comment: @gdvalderrama thanks, I've updated my answer with the 5.1 link.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need it. 
Without the container it kind a works - but it shows a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the page and around 20px are cut off from rightside of the screen.

See yourself how it works without the container class - just go to http://getbootstrap.com/ and remove the container class using inspect element.

Comment: That site is not using the flud width / fluid layout though so that doesnt really apply. If using a full-width layout you no longer need the container since container-fluid was removed from BS3.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the container-fluid class instead of the container class. 
class="container-fluid" will allow you to use full width.

Comment: Wasn't container-fluid removed from Bootstrap 3 in favour of just using rows and columns?

Comment: container-fluid was added back into Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Container-fluid however, has a max width of 1200px