# Nested bootstrap rows & columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nested

Hi i am trying to achieve the following layout

[image]
using the following html, css and bootstrap classes

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 fix-result">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="fix-result-info">friendly Match | 23 July 2016 | The Muga | KO 14:30 </p>
            <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                    <p>WON</p>
                    <h4>Team A 2-1 Team B</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 match-details">
                <p>goalscorers</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.fix-result {padding:10px;border: 1px solid #0359cf; margin-bottom:20px;}
.fix-result-info { color: #0359cf;text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;}
.fix-result .match-details {padding:10px;background-color: #0359cf;}
```

fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kngsne42/

However, the blue div keeps floating outside the scope of the parent div and i am unsure how to resolve the issue.

[image]

Am i nesting the rows and columns correctly?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: row just means no carriage return. since you're already in a row, you shouldn't have another one

Comment: The best and easiest way would probably be to simply treat this as two separate rows, the first one containing a col-12 and the second one two col-6 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're supposed to nest rows.
Also, you should put rows inside a container.

(see also: [Bootstrap 3 Grid, do I need a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063976/bootstrap-3-grid-do-i-need-a-container))

The following code seems to do the trick:

```css
.fix-result {padding-right:20px;border: 1px solid #0359cf; margin-bottom:20px;}
.fix-result-info { color: #0359cf;text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;}
.fix-result .match-details {padding:10px;background-color: #0359cf;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-xs-12 fix-result">
        <p class="fix-result-info">friendly Match | 23 July 2016 | The Muga | KO 14:30 </p>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
            <p>WON</p>
            <h4>Team A 2-1 Team B</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 match-details">
            <p>goalscorers</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi sorry, i do have a conatiner but forgot to add it to my example. I was looking at the Nesting columns part on this page http://getbootstrap.com/css/. It appears to nest a row. Thanks for your suggestions ill give it a go

Comment: _"I don't think you're supposed to nest rows"_ - neither are you supposed to use `row` and `col-` classes on the same element. While this might "work" here, I'd not be surprised if it causes additional alignment problems later on or within a bigger context.

Comment: The col and row was a syntax error sorry. Lot of copy and paste happening. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row fix-result">
        <p class="fix-result-info">friendly Match | 23 July 2016 | The Muga | KO 14:30 </p>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="text-center">
                <p>WON</p>
                <h4>Team A 2-1 Team B</h4>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="match-details">
            <p>goalscorers</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

just make change in tag of .
It will work.