# how to remove the padding in the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

please help fix this page.

have adaptive [page](http://jsfiddle.net/uh9Tw/), here is the [view](http://pixs.ru/showimage/im1png_4855941_12740427.png). (at the edges of the block .wrap_c have padding). I would like to remake the page and lead to such a [view](http://pixs.ru/showimage/im2png_9687818_12740433.png) (on the sides of the block .wrap_c no indentation). wherein the width of the block. wrap_c should remain the same

please tell me how to do it or where to find the disc select my desired page.

html:

```
<div class="container wrap_c">
    <div class="row navbar_outer_r">                
        sggd<br>
        sggd<br>
        sggd<br>
    </div>

    sggd<br>
    sggd<br>
    sggd<br>

    <div class="content_area">
        <div class="page_home_area">
            <div class="row our_works_r">
                sggd<br>
                sggd<br>
                sggd<br>
            </div>  

            sggd<br>
            sggd<br>
            sggd<br>                    

            <div class="row making_box_r">
                <div class="text_area_outer col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1  col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">  
                    <div class="text_area clearfix radius10">   
                        <div class="left_area col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                            sggd<br>
                            sggd<br>
                            sggd<br>    
                        </div>

                        <div class="right_area col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                            sggd<br>
                            sggd<br>
                            sggd<br>    
                        </div>                              
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row production_r">
                sggd<br>
                sggd<br>
                sggd<br>                            
            </div>                      
        </div>                  
    </div>                  
</div>

<div class="container footer_c">
    <div class="row footer_r">
        <div class="row address_bottom_r">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 address_bottom_left">   
                sggd<br>
                sggd<br>
                sggd<br>                            
            </div>  

            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 address_bottom_right">  
                sggd<br>
                sggd<br>
                sggd<br>                                                    
            </div>                      
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not much related but you can use http://www.bootply.com for bootstrap testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `container-liquid` instead of `container` in your first div.

Comment: Did you mean container-fluid?

Comment: @EduardoDennis :) RLOL, it's where i got it from http://stackoverflow.com/a/18475756/27186

Answer (score 1):

Try `container-fluid` instead of `container` in your first div.